# XMLSerializer invalid serialize to XML

Tags: .net, xml, xml-serialization

I have the next code for serialization class to XML:

```
public void TestActionPost(Dictionary<string, int> myDictionary)
{
    List<DataItem> tempdataitems = new List<DataItem>();

    if (myDictionary != null)
    {
        foreach (string key in myDictionary.Keys)
        {
            tempdataitems.Add(new DataItem(key, myDictionary[key]));
        }
    }

    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
    settings.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.None;
    settings.Indent = false;
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<DataItem>));
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sw, settings);
    XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    namespaces.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);
    serializer.Serialize(sw, tempdataitems, namespaces);
    string xml = sw.ToString();

}
```

I get next XML string output:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>\r\n<ArrayOfDataItem>\r\n  <DataItem>\r\n    <ApplicationItemId>4929</ApplicationItemId>\r\n    <OrderNumber>0</OrderNumber>\r\n  </DataItem>\r\n  <DataItem>\r\n    <ApplicationItemId>1469407</ApplicationItemId>\r\n    <OrderNumber>1</OrderNumber>\r\n  </DataItem>\r\n</ArrayOfDataItem>
```

Then I want to pass this xml to stored procedure to save data to database. But my script don't work because this string contain `\r\n` and `\` in `<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>` string. I try to delete this chars by hand and it work greate.

How I can get normal xml string without this characters?

P.S.

It's method call stored procedure and pass my XML:

```
public void SaveApplicationItemsOrder(string xml)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(LcciCarnetConnectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("saveApplicationItemsOrder", connection);
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    SqlParameter parameter = command.Parameters.Add("@xml", SqlDbType.Xml);
                    parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    parameter.Value = xml;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@rowcount", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                } 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Log.Error("Application service error", ex);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this problem!

I delete first string of xml(xml declaration) `<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>` because I don't find resolving how to delete `/` character in xml declaration.

And delete all `/r/n` characters in serialized xml by this code:

```
public void TestActionPost(Dictionary<string, int> myDictionary)
    {
        List<DataItem> tempdataitems = new List<DataItem>();

        if (myDictionary != null)
        {
            foreach (string key in myDictionary.Keys)
            {
                tempdataitems.Add(new DataItem(key, myDictionary[key]));
            }
        }

        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;  **//delete xml declaration**

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<DataItem>));
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        sw.NewLine = ""; **//delete /r/n**
        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sw, settings);
        XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        namespaces.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, tempdataitems, namespaces);
        string xml = sw.ToString();

    }
```